# What is the Big-O Time complexity of this recursive call with a for-loop

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

Question, when analyzing the time complexity of the following code (never mind the space complexity). Would this be O(n)? the recursive call count as constant? I'm not sure because of the recursive call within the for loop.

```
public void printViews(View view) {
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup && ((ViewGroup)view).getChildCount() > 0) {

            ViewGroup viewGroup = ((ViewGroup)view);
            int childCount = viewGroup.getChildCount();

            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                Log.d("Test", viewGroup.getChildAt(i).getClass().getSimpleName());

                if (viewGroup.getChildAt(i) instanceof ViewGroup)
                    printViews(viewGroup.getChildAt(i));  //recursion
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Test", view.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are going to say "Would this be O(n)", you need to be clear about what n is.

Comment: @AndyTurner thank you for the comment. n as in the number of child views. Didn't realize until Shuki pointed out, I'm just traversing a tree of views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is O(n).

What you are doing is DFS on the view tree.
The recursive call is not constant but it is a way of traversing the tree.

see the link for more details:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 3):

It is O(n). Since you are traversing through the tree hierarchy once. The recursive method even though it is inside the for loop is serving the purpose of traversing the view and its descendants.